# jquery autocomplete tagging

Tags: jquery, python, django

Can any one tell me how to use tagging auto-complete in django templates?

I have done this in django admin interface but i am confused to how to do it in the template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a new solution from February 2012:
http://nemesisdesign.net/blog/coding/django-tagging-autocomplete-tag-it-jquery-ui/

Answer (score 2):

In my template i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tags1").autocomplete("/taglookup/", {
        width: 320,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: " "
         });
   }
```

and on my url.py i have this on the urlparttern tuple, it can be anything depending on how you want to wire you views and urls!

```
(r'^taglookup/$', 'twine.twineapp.views.tag_lookup')
```

and on my views.py i have the tag_lookup view implemented as:

```
def tag_lookup(request):
    # Default return list
    results = []
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET.has_key(u'q'):
            value = request.GET[u'q']
            # Ignore queries shorter than length 2
            if len(value) > 2:
               TI = Tag.objects.filter(name__startswith=value.lower())
               results = [ x.name for x in TI]
    return HttpResponse('\n'.join(results), mimetype='text/plain')
```

PS: Am using the [Tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) package, that's why i have the Tag object in the above code.

Comment: +1. However, I guess this can become slow if you've thousands of tags, because it will create a list every time you call `tag_lookup`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [my django-tagging-autocomplete reusable app](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging-autocomplete/) and take advantage of provided TagAutocomplete form widget. You can find out more about using the widget [in the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging-autocomplete/wiki/ReadMe) under "Using the form widget".

Please note that the app requires you use django-tagging for your tags. You also need to put `{{ form.media }}` (where "form" is the name of your form) inside the `<head>` section in your template, to allow the widget to include it's JavaScript files.

Comment: "all the css and javascript is imported"... so if you look in the source `jquery.autocomplete.js` is included in the header, and there is a snippet of JavaScript code next to the `<input>` code? It should work. Also make sure that the URL used for retrieving list of tags via AJAX is accessible. If that doesn't help, could you provide me with URL of an example?

Comment: this is very important information but doc does not mention it :( thanks @Ludwik Trammer

Comment: hey can u tell me, how did you do it in the Django Admin interface..??..any third party app..??..which one ..??..any docs available ??

Comment: @RamandeepSingh I'm not sure I understand your question. You can read about customizing Django's admin site here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/

If you are interested about things that django-tagging-autocomplete do in particular, you can check out the source. It's pretty short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is from a template where I implemented autocomplete

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#searchbox").autocomplete('/search_stuff/', {
        width: 300,
        multiple: false,
        matchContains: true,
        delay: 900,
        extraParams: {
               s: function() { return $("#status").val(); }
        }
});
```

Where search_stuff return a text list of all the items that fitted the criteria.  Does that help?

Comment: i don't know all the javascript and css are imported correctly ..but it didn't still work....can any one suggest some thing new..